# Circular dependency in interface

Tags: typescript, mongodb, mongoose, next.js

I have this `interface` defining a schema in my MongoDB where I'm using mongoose as an ODM

```js
import mongoose, { model, Schema, Model, Document } from "mongoose";

import { IUser } from "./user";
import { IPost } from "./posts";

export interface IComment extends Document {
  post: IPost;
  replyTo: IComment;
  owner: IUser;
  content: string;
  replies: IComment[];
  createdAt: Date;
  updatedAt: Date;
  upvotes: number;
  downvotes: number;
}

// ...mongoose schema declaration omitted
```

When I try to compile the Typescript I get this:

```
Type error: Type of property 'replyTo' circularly references itself in mapped type 'LeanDocument<IComment>'.
```

This never happened to me when I was using `mongoose@5.13.5` but I had to upgrade to `mongoose@6.0.3` so that I could connect to my serverless instance on Atlas. I don't think downgrading is a option. How to I resolve this circular dependencies issue?

Answer (score 0):

This shouldn't be dependent on your mongoose version.  This error is related to the TypeScript version in use.  Recursive types are allowed as of TypeScript 3.7 https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/33050

Comment: I'm on Typescript^4.3.5 and ts-node^10.2.1. Though yeah this is obviously a problem with typescript not mongo..